# Permissions error when moving source from one project to another in TFS2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I have ProjectA with folder XYZ under it in source control in TFS2010.  I use VS2010 to move the folder to ProjectB.  I have a Rename pending change.  The projects are mapped to 2 different folders on my local disk.  The move operation copied all the files to the ProjectB local folder.
When I try to Checkin the change, I get the following error:
TF14098: Access Denied: User PROD_SYSTEM\TOBKRAF needs Checkin permission(s) for $/ProjectA/XYZ/*. - which of course no longer exists since I'm in the process of moving it.

Now it might be saying that it's trying to do something at the project level and I don't have rights so I'm going to give myself project admin permissions and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer was that I really needed some higher level of rights (even though I had checkin/checkout in the project) - Logging in as Administrator and doing the move worked.